# Repeated Error in Building the Xcode Project with Version Xcode 11.4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

After updating my Xcode to the version 11.4, and building my previous firebase project I am facing this error in pods file "Pods-Project19-resources.sh". I deleted the pod lock file and then again I install the pods , but still the same error is happening.

You can see the error in the screen shot shared. Please assist.

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

Answer (score 0):

Created new project and copied everything to the new project. It didn't resolved in the earlier configuration of the project.